# Remove space between divs vertically [Bootsrap 3]

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need to remove space between some `div` and `div below that div`. Space created if some div is higer then other in column.

Here is example:

http://www.bootply.com/Hc2aO5o4bG

basicly I need to remove space between `1. and 4.` post and `2. and 5.` and for each other posts that have space below them.

Also post should be in this order:

```
1. 2. 3.
4. 5. 6.
7. .....
```

Here is what I trying to accomplish:
[image]

Comment: Check this out, looks like a valid solution [responsive columns of same height](http://www.minimit.com/demos/bootstrap-3-responsive-columns-of-same-height)

Comment: What about using columns and re-organizing the contents of your divs (the posts) before displaying them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give a clear before `4`:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 hover">
  <!-- post thumbnail -->
  <!-- /post thumbnail -->
  <div class="content">
    <h4><a href="http://tuts.masterize.me/2014/06/24/iq-test-php-mysql/" title="IQ test [PHP &amp; MySQL]">IQ test [PHP &amp; MySQL]</a></h4> 
    <p>
    </p><p>We have 4 columns: iq_id, iq_pitanje, iq_odgovor and iq_tacan. iq_tacan contains true answer.</p>                                            <a class="post-edit-link" href="http://tuts.masterize.me/wp-admin/post.php?post=1284&amp;action=edit">Edit This</a>                                            <p></p>
  </div>
  <a href="http://tuts.masterize.me/2014/06/24/iq-test-php-mysql/">
    <div class="link">
      <i class="fa fa-link"></i>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 hover">
  <!-- post thumbnail -->
  <!-- /post thumbnail -->
  <div class="content">
    <h4><a href="http://tuts.masterize.me/2014/06/24/iq-test-php-mysql/" title="IQ test [PHP &amp; MySQL]">IQ test [PHP &amp; MySQL]</a></h4> 
    <p>
    </p><p>We have 4 cssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss
    ssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssolumns: iq_id, iq_pit
    anje, iq_odgovor and iq_tacan. iq_tacan contains true answer.</p>                                            <a class="post-edit-link" href="http://tuts.masterize.me/wp-admin/post.php?post=1284&amp;action=edit">Edit This</a>                                            <p></p>
  </div>
  <a href="http://tuts.masterize.me/2014/06/24/iq-test-php-mysql/">
    <div class="link">
      <i class="fa fa-link"></i>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 hover">
  <!-- post thumbnail -->
  <!-- /post thumbnail -->
  <div class="content">
    <h4><a href="http://tuts.masterize.me/2014/06/24/iq-test-php-mysql/" title="IQ test [PHP &amp; MySQL]">IQ test [PHP &amp; MySQL]</a></h4> 
    <p>
    </p><p>We have 4 columns: iq_id, iq_pitanje, iq_odgovor and iq_tacan. iq_tacan contains true answer.</p>                                            <a class="post-edit-link" href="http://tuts.masterize.me/wp-admin/post.php?post=1284&amp;action=edit">Edit This</a>                                            <p></p>
  </div>
  <a href="http://tuts.masterize.me/2014/06/24/iq-test-php-mysql/">
    <div class="link">
      <i class="fa fa-link"></i>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 hover">
  <!-- post thumbnail -->
  <!-- /post thumbnail -->
  <div class="content">
    <h4><a href="http://tuts.masterize.me/2014/06/24/iq-test-php-mysql/" title="IQ test [PHP &amp; MySQL]">IQ test [PHP &amp; MySQL]</a></h4> 
    <p>
    </p><p>We have 4 columns: iq_id, iq_pitanje, iq_odgovor and iq_tacan. iq_tacan contains true answer.</p>                                            <a class="post-edit-link" href="http://tuts.masterize.me/wp-admin/post.php?post=1284&amp;action=edit">Edit This</a>                                            <p></p>
  </div>
  <a href="http://tuts.masterize.me/2014/06/24/iq-test-php-mysql/">
    <div class="link">
      <i class="fa fa-link"></i>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 hover">
  <!-- post thumbnail -->
  <!-- /post thumbnail -->
  <div class="content">
    <h4><a href="http://tuts.masterize.me/2014/06/24/iq-test-php-mysql/" title="IQ test [PHP &amp; MySQL]">IQ test [PHP &amp; MySQL]</a></h4> 
    <p>
    </p><p>We have 4 columns: iq_id, iq_pitanje, iq_odgovor and iq_tacan. iq_tacan contains true answer.</p>                                            <a class="post-edit-link" href="http://tuts.masterize.me/wp-admin/post.php?post=1284&amp;action=edit">Edit This</a>                                            <p></p>
  </div>
  <a href="http://tuts.masterize.me/2014/06/24/iq-test-php-mysql/">
    <div class="link">
      <i class="fa fa-link"></i>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 hover">
  <!-- post thumbnail -->
  <!-- /post thumbnail -->
  <div class="content">
    <h4><a href="http://tuts.masterize.me/2014/06/24/iq-test-php-mysql/" title="IQ test [PHP &amp; MySQL]">IQ test [PHP &amp; MySQL]</a></h4> 
    <p>
    </p><p>We have 4 columns: iq_id, iq_pitanje, iq_odgovor and iq_tacan. iq_tacan contains true answer.</p>                                            <a class="post-edit-link" href="http://tuts.masterize.me/wp-admin/post.php?post=1284&amp;action=edit">Edit This</a>                                            <p></p>
  </div>
  <a href="http://tuts.masterize.me/2014/06/24/iq-test-php-mysql/">
    <div class="link">
      <i class="fa fa-link"></i>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

And give this CSS

```
.clear {
  clear: both;
}
```

Technically, you must give the `.clear` every three rows, in your case!

**Preview: http://www.bootply.com/uC3qzah3f9**

---

For a dynamic solution:

```css
/* Start Praveen's Reset for Fiddle ;) */
* {font-family: 'Segoe UI'; margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;}
/* End Praveen's Reset for Fiddle ;) */
.posts {overflow: hidden;}
.posts .post {border: 1px solid #999; padding: 10px; text-align: center; width: 32%; margin: 0.5%; float: left;}
.posts .post:nth-child(3n+4):before {clear: both; display: block; content: " ";}
```

```html
<div class="posts">
  <div class="post">Post #1</div>
  <div class="post">Post #2</div>
  <div class="post">Post #3</div>
  <div class="post">Post #4</div>
  <div class="post">Post #5</div>
  <div class="post">Post #6</div>
  <div class="post">Post #7</div>
  <div class="post">Post #8</div>
  <div class="post">Post #9</div>
  <div class="post">Post #10</div>
  <div class="post">Post #11</div>
  <div class="post">Post #12</div>
  <div class="post">Post #13</div>
  <div class="post">Post #14</div>
  <div class="post">Post #15</div>
</div>
```

In the above case, you need to manually change the CSS: `(3n + 4)`. I gave `+ 4` to not include the 1st child.

Comment: But when posts are dynamically added how can I know where to `clear` ?

Comment: @VladimirDjukic Either you need to have a counter in the server side, or you need to output only three rows at a time. Else I have another solution that I am working. Give me sometime.

Comment: In the above case, you need to manually change the CSS: (3n + 4). I gave + 4 to not include the 1st child.

Comment: But problem with this I can't know where to `clear` because space can be before any post... for exaple if I add extra hight on 3. posts it will also make space: http://jsfiddle.net/730rawnd/ ...

Comment: Are you saying all the posts should be of same height?

Comment: No, all post can be different height. I am saying I am not able to find which post create space when content is added dynamically...

Comment: @VladimirDjukic Check this. Keep two posts of random height and check. It works!!!

Comment: But I don't want post be same size... :) I just wana remove space

Comment: @VladimirDjukic Have you checked [**jQuery Masonry**](http://masonry.desandro.com/) yet?

Comment: Yes, but still no idea what to do... :(

Answer (score 2):

You should be wrapping your rows with `<div class="row"></div>`: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

You can also set a min-height property to something like 141px so that the borders line up.

Comment: I'm not saying wrap all of the divs in a single row. However, the classes you are using col-md-4 col-xs-12 have specific uses. Use .row to group columns horizontally. By default rows should add up to 12, so in your case, they will stack no matter what on mobile (col-xs-12) and be 3 to a horizontal row on medium and large devices (as you have no col-lg-*). I linked to the documentation that explains how to use the bootstrap grid.

Comment: I see what you are trying to accomplish now. Bootstrap will not handle that. Try a masonry framework like http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: This can be useful, I will try with it. Thanks